# How to append ?=CONTENT on all static links

Tags: jquery, cookies

When using an email campaign, there's a referrer string added to the link when they visit the page:

```
?utm_source=email&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=campaign_name
```

So when they visit my index.html page will have the URL in the address bar:

```
/index.html?utm_source=email&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=a_certain_campaign_name_set_in_the_email
```

When they click one of my relative links .eg: `<a href="/pages/about.html">About</a>` the campaign ID is lost. Is there a way client-side of keeping this randomly generated URL on the end of the links in the browser address bar?

I do not have access to the server side CMS, so it can only be a client-side solution. I've looked at jQuery Cookies plugin, but can't figure out how to remember and restore the string.

Answer (score 0):

If you're tracking these users via Google Analytics, you should be able to continue tracking where they have visited on your site via the GA cookies.

I believe the specific cookie that you'll be looking for is `__utmz`

Check these links for more information:

http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/concepts/gaConceptsCookies.html

http://services.google.com/analytics/breeze/en/ga_cookies/index.html (page 10 explains utmz parsing)

Comment: Hi Anthony, I need to keep the string in the URL as when they visit a certain page it will look for the referrer code and offer them a special introductory rate based on that campaign.

Comment: you should be able to retrieve that information from the cookie. utmcsr will give you the source (referrer) and utmccn will give you the campaign. I added a couple of links that should provide more information